# How to interpret SVM output in Weka?

Tags: svm, weka

I have a Support Vector model in Weka (SMO) and I want to extract knowledge from this output:

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===
    SMO
    Kernel used:
      Puk kernel
    Classifier for classes: Positive, Negative
    BinarySMO
          0.9349 * <0.364865 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 > * X]
     +       0.743  * <0.486486 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 > * X]
     +       0.8578 * <0.391892 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 > * X]
     -       0.815  * <0.297297 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 > * X]
     -       0.2347 * <0.391892 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 > * X]
     +       1.1502 * <0.527027 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 > * X]
     +       0.6922 * <0.554054 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 > * X]
     .....
     -       0.3291 * <0.594595 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 > * X]
     +       0.9296 * <0.364865 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 > * X]
     +       0.6504 * <0.351351 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 > * X]
     -       0.0333 * <0.27027 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 > * X]
     +       0.0085 * <0.513514 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 > * X]
     +       0.8176 * <0.72973 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 > * X]
     -       0.4812 * <1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 > * X]
     -       0.3286 * <0.256757 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 > * X]
     .........
     -       0.1838 * <0.635135 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 > * X]
     -       0.0976 * <0.189189 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 > * X]
     -       0.0036 * <0.364865 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 > * X]
     -       0.0157 * <0.554054 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 > * X]
    .........
     -       0.0167 * <0.621622 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 > * X]
     +       0.2005 * <0.5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 > * X]
     -       0.589 
Number of support vectors: 378
Number of kernel evaluations: 131997 (92.5% cached)
```

How can I interpret this output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SMO's [toString()](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.java#L753) method to see how the output is constructed. Check out the [Puk kernel](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7b19faa2980f9a7f4c3de0f10f1e75c8f1cb52b1/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/supportVector/Puk.java) itself ([publication](http://www.cac.science.ru.nl/research/publications/PDFs/ustun2006.pdf)), to see how its calculations are done.

The textual output of classifiers is usually only for informative purposes (it is optional and has no impact on a classifier). People usually apply trained models directly to new data rather than trying to understand the output (especially with support vector machines).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems hard to understand the whole method. I would like to know: what do the `+` and `-` mean? Are lower numbers between `+`/`-` and `*` worst than the higher ones?

Comment: No idea. An introductory text book into support vector machines might shed some light on that.